# Quid iuvat deōs precāri ut rēs āmissae tibi reddantur?

Tags: lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

On page 234 line 44-45 of lingua latina per se illustrata pars 1 the following text appears: "Quid iuvat deōs precāri ut rēs āmissae tibi reddantur?".

I am trying to comprehend this, but I no have clear idea what is supposed to be the subject, given the use of *Quid* instead of *Quis* expecting something of the lines of *Who asks the gods...*.

Secondarily, the accusative with infinitive *deós precárí* is understood by me as *askings to the gods* but it's not clear what it is supposed to mean when interacting with the verb *iuvat*. After the *ut* I think I have the meaning as *things that you lose return to you*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Quid iuvat?* is a bit of a set phrase meaning 'what's the point?', 'what good does it do?' or, more literally, 'what does it help?'. The matter in question being *deos precari* 'to pray to the gods' (note the infinitive). So piecing it together: what good does it do to pray to the gods?

You have the latter part right, but perhaps more exactly 'that things that you have lost return (are given back) to you'.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with consistebat's answer. Since I see that you are also interested in the syntax (cf. "I don't have a clear idea about what is supposed to be the subject"), here are some comments on the syntactic analysis, which, hopefully, can help you understand the precise meaning of the example:

The subject of *iuvat* is the infinitival clause (*deōs precāri ut rēs āmissae tibi reddantur*). In your example *quid* can be analyzed as having a sort of an *adverbial* function (cf. the accusative of relation or limitation). Literally: 'in what does it help to pray...'.

*Precāri* is a deponent verb that can be found with two internal arguments: the personal accusative (*deos*) and the *ut*-clause (*ut rēs āmissae tibi reddantur*). The predicative frame is *precāri aliquem aliquid*, the neuter thing argument being replaced by the *ut*-clause [NB: this is not the only possible predicative frame of this verb. See this [link](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=precor) for a list of them].